# BHO: where to write to regisitry?

Tags: c#, bho, ieaddon

In C++, Browser Helper Objects should use IEGetWriteableHKCU to know where they can right to the registry. What is the equivalent function for C#? I want to save user preferences, it looks like the right way to do it on Windows it to use the registry.

Comment: The registry is rarely the right place to put user preferences. The user's Application Data folder is almost always preferred.

Comment: I was looking for a "Best Practice" document from SM, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: that's because the best practice is not to write to the registry for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me it's just a function exported from IEFRAME.DLL :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537315(v=vs.85).aspx

Therefore you can probably just use P/Invoke to call it, I might be a bit off on the signature here so anyone feel free to edit it:

```
[DllImport("ieframe.dll")]
public extern long IEGetWriteableHKCU(out IntPtr hKey);
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any example on how to use it?